# My ReCaptcha mailer won't work

Tags: php, recaptcha, autoload, mailer

I'm fine-tuning this website for a school project, but my ReCaptcha mailer keeps returning an HTTP ERROR 500. Can someone help me and find the problem?

This is the website: http://i385436.hera.fhict.nl/cates/contact.html

I'm guessing the fault is in the two PHP-files: contact.php and autoload.php, which are both pre-made and downloaded (since I'm pretty noob when it comes to PHP). I believe I configured every setting within the files, like getting my reCaptcha keys etc.

This is the code for contact.php:

```
<?php
// require ReCaptcha class
require('autoload.php');

// configure
$from = 'tgdtom@gmail.com';
$sendTo = 'tgdtom@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Bericht via Cates contactformulier';
$fields = array('name' => 'Naam', 'email' => 'Email', 'phone' => 'Tel.nr.', 'message' => 'Bericht'); // array variable name => Text to appear in the email
$okMessage = 'Uw bericht is met succes verzonden, u krijgt zo snel mogelijk reactie!';
$errorMessage = 'Er is iets fout gegaan met het versturen van uw bericht, probeer het later nog eens of neem telefonisch contact op.';
$recaptchaSecret = '6Lf9ZzUUAAAAAL7qstYlXD8pE8LCvpsDWWlvsW5-';

// let's do the sending

try
{
    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        // validate the ReCaptcha, if something is wrong, we throw an Exception, 
        // i.e. code stops executing and goes to catch() block

        if (!isset($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'])) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha is not set.');
        }

        // do not forget to enter your secret key in the config above 
        // from https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

        $recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($recaptchaSecret, new \ReCaptcha\RequestMethod\CurlPost());

        // we validate the ReCaptcha field together with the user's IP address

        $response = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);


        if (!$response->isSuccess()) {
            throw new \Exception('ReCaptcha was not validated.');
        }

        // everything went well, we can compose the message, as usually

        $emailText = "You have new message from contact form\n=============================\n";

        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

            if (isset($fields[$key])) {
                $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
            }
        }


        $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
            'From: ' . $from,
            'Reply-To: ' . $from,
            'Return-Path: ' . $from,
        );

        mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

        $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' => $errorMessage);
}

if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
    $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    echo $encoded;
}
else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
}
```

And this is autoload.php:

```
<?php
/* An autoloader for ReCaptcha\Foo classes. This should be required()
 * by the user before attempting to instantiate any of the ReCaptcha
 * classes.
 */
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    if (substr($class, 0, 10) !== 'ReCaptcha\\') {
      /* If the class does not lie under the "ReCaptcha" namespace,
       * then we can exit immediately.
       */
      return;
    }
    /* All of the classes have names like "ReCaptcha\Foo", so we need
     * to replace the backslashes with frontslashes if we want the
     * name to map directly to a location in the filesystem.
     */
    $class = str_replace('\\', '/', $class);
    /* First, check under the current directory. It is important that
     * we look here first, so that we don't waste time searching for
     * test classes in the common case.
     */
    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/'.$class.'.php';
    if (is_readable($path)) {
        require_once $path;
    }
    /* If we didn't find what we're looking for already, maybe it's
     * a test class?
     */
    $path = dirname(__FILE__).'/../tests/'.$class.'.php';
    if (is_readable($path)) {
        require_once $path;
    }
});
```

I hope you guys/girls can find the problems, or have a better alternative for me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're getting a 500 error, you need to check your error logs.

Comment: Sorry if this is a dumb question, but where can I find that?